# Composed primary keys : "should" duplicates and null values be accepted, and according to which norm?

Tags: primary-key, duplication, sql-standard

I just passed some SQL test including a question about the possibility to have duplicates in a primary key column.
The expected answer was NO.  Mine is, "Yes, *if* the column is part of a composed primary key".

I did some testing to check that I was right, and my MySQL has no problem with this at all.

Null values, on the other hand, weren't accepted.  Only converted to 0 if using non-strict mode

---

I tried to check for the official norm, which I assume would be the iso specification... but it's not free : https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/fr/#iso:std:iso-iec:9075:-1:ed-5:v1:en

I'm not sure using columns allowing duplicates as part of primary keys make much sense, but fact is, it's *possible*.

Is what I'm seeing with MySQL specific to that DBMS?

I don't have any other DBMS at the current time, but would be interested to know if SQL Server, PostgreSQL or Oracle Database have stricter restrictions about this.

---

Edit : here's what I did on my MySQL

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS pk_dup_test;
CREATE DATABASE pk_dup_test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pk_dup_test`.`datadup`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pk_dup_test`.`datasimple`;


CREATE TABLE `pk_dup_test`.`datasimple` (
  `id`  INT,
  `val` INT,
  CONSTRAINT datasimple_primary  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

);
###############################
INSERT INTO `pk_dup_test`.`datasimple`(id, val)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 22), (3, 31337), (4, 42), (5, 7), (6, 666), (7, 62);



CREATE TABLE `pk_dup_test`.`datadup` (
   `id1` INT UNIQUE
  ,`id2` INT 
  ,`id3` INT UNIQUE
  ,`val` INT
  ,`name` TEXT

  ,CONSTRAINT datadup_primary        PRIMARY KEY (`id1`, `id2`, `id3`)
  ,CONSTRAINT datadup_foreign_naive  FOREIGN KEY (`val`) REFERENCES `pk_dup_test`.`datasimple`(id)
  ,CONSTRAINT datadup_foreign_on_pk  FOREIGN KEY (`id1`) REFERENCES `pk_dup_test`.`datasimple`(id)
);
########################################
DELETE FROM `pk_dup_test`.`datadup`;
INSERT INTO `pk_dup_test`.`datadup` (id1, id2, id3, val)
VALUES
     (1, 2, 3, 4)
    ,(2, 2, 2, 4)
    ,(3, 2, 1, 2)
    ,(5, 0, 4, 2)
;
```

Everything works fine, with strict mode.

I checked the table constraints and inserted lines. Nothing is missing. (and 3 lines have id2=2)

The tables are using InnoDB.
Tested with  phpMyAdmin, on WAMP  and *MySQL version 5.6.17*.

Comment: Post test to demonstrate duplicate values in a PK.

Comment: @MichaelKutz done.